# Javascript Drag Drop Swaps :a way to filling the blanks

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use native html5 javascript drag and drop function to create my own filling the blank script.

But now I have a problem with swapping and replace the boxes. When I drag a box into the not empty box, instead of replacing, the box is appended to it.

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  if (ev.target.tagName == "DIV") {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));

    var srcParent = data.parentNode;
    var tgt = ev.currentTarget.firstElementChild;

    ev.currentTarget.replaceChild(data, tgt);
    ev.appendChild(data);


  } else {
    console.log(ev.target.childNodes);
  }

}
```

```css
.text-secondary {
  color: #6c757d !important;
}

.card-body {
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 1.25rem;
}

p,
a,
body,
button,
label,
img,
div,
i,
span,
footer,
header,
section,
textarea,
input,
select {
  font-family: Segoe !important;
}

* {
  font-family: Segoe !important;
}

*,
::after,
::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

user agent stylesheet div {
  display: block;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 0;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: border-box;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
  border-radius: .25rem;
}

.ml-1,
.mx-1 {
  margin-left: .25rem !important;
}

.mr-1,
.mx-1 {
  margin-right: .25rem !important;
}

.border-dark {
  border-color: #343a40 !important;
}

.border {
  border: 1px solid #dee2e6 !important;
}

#fillstodrag div {
  margin: 30px !important;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-body text-secondary">



  <span style="line-height:40px;" class="font-weight-bold">The</span>


  <div ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" class=" border border-dark mx-1" style="display:inline-block;height: 1.6rem; width: 9rem;margin-right:4px;margin-left:2px; ">



  </div>


  <span style="line-height:40px;" class="font-weight-bold">observer recognize the</span>
  <div ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" class=" border border-dark mx-1" style="display:inline-block;height: 1.6rem; width: 9rem;margin-right:4px;margin-left:2px; ">



  </div>


  <span style="line-height:40px;" class="font-weight-bold">in how a teacher inquisitive or</span>
  <div ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" class=" border border-dark mx-1" style="display:inline-block;height: 1.6rem; width: 9rem;margin-right:4px;margin-left:2px; ">



  </div>


  <span style="line-height:40px;" class="font-weight-bold">student. </span>

  <div class="card-body text-secondary" id="fillstodrag" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">









    <div style="margin-right:2px;float:left;height: 1.6rem; width: 9rem; text-align: center" id="59_193_2" draggable="true" class="border border-primary font-weight-bold" ondragstart="drag(event)">good
    </div>








    <div style="margin-right:2px;float:left;height: 1.6rem; width: 9rem; text-align: center" id="59_187_3" draggable="true" class="border border-primary font-weight-bold" ondragstart="drag(event)">talkative
    </div>








    <div style="margin-right:2px;float:left;height: 1.6rem; width: 9rem; text-align: center" id="59_191_4" draggable="true" class="border border-primary font-weight-bold" ondragstart="drag(event)">professional
    </div>


























    <div style="margin-right:2px;float:left;height: 1.6rem; width: 9rem; text-align: center" id="59_192_9" draggable="true" class="border border-primary font-weight-bold" ondragstart="drag(event)">quiet
    </div>








    <div style="margin-right:2px;float:left;height: 1.6rem; width: 9rem; text-align: center" id="59_185_10" draggable="true" class="border border-primary font-weight-bold" ondragstart="drag(event)">skill
    </div>



  </div>
```

Demo link :

http://jsfiddle.net/urbdt268/5/